# Swagger Codegen for OAS3

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I'm trying to use Swagger Codegen for my OAS3 project.
I have cloned swagger-codegen branch 3.0.0. and when I run the generate command I get the following error:

```
[main] ERROR io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter - failed to read resource listing
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'openapi': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

 at [Source: (String)"openapi: 3.0.0
```

Does Codegen supports openapi 3.0.1 yet? If yes what am I missing ?

UPDATE - Yaml file and codegen command

Petstore.yaml file :

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Petstore
  license:
    name: MIT
servers:
  - url: http://petstore.swagger.io/v1
paths:
  /pets:
    get:
      summary: List all pets
      operationId: listPets
      tags:
        - pets
      parameters:
        - name: limit
          in: query
          description: How many items to return at one time (max 100)
          required: false
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int32
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A paged array of pets
          headers:
            x-next:
              description: A link to the next page of responses
              schema:
                type: string
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pets"
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"
    post:
      summary: Create a pet
      operationId: createPets
      tags:
        - pets
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Null response
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      type: object
      required:
        - id
        - name
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
        tag:
          type: string
    Pets:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
    Error:
      type: object
      required:
        - code
        - message
      properties:
        code:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        message:
          type: string
```

Codegen command:

```
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

java -jar ./swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i "./definitions/petstoreV3.yaml" -l javascript -o "$SCRIPT_DIR/.swagger_gen_temp"
```

Comment: Yes Swagger Codegen supports OAS 3.0.1. Please post your YAML/JSON file and the full command you ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you are running V2 codegen (from the `master` branch) instead of V3 codegen (from the `3.0.0` branch). V2 codegen does not support OpenAPI 3.0.

You can download the JAR of V3 codegen from:
http://central.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/codegen/v3/swagger-codegen-cli/3.0.11/swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.11.jar

V3 codegen, however, does not currently have a JavaScript client generator.